# $httpBackend returns empty object (Expected Object({ }) to equal )

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am new to Unit Testing, and am trying to test a service, using $httpBackend.

Here's some code i have:

```
.factory('Configuration', function($http, $rootScope, $localStorage) {
    return $http.get('some/url', {cache: true}).success(function(response) { return response; })
        .then(function(response){

            return (response.data.some.thing) || {};

        });
})
```

config goes here, in the modules .config():

```
$routeProvider.when('/something/:id', {templateUrl: 'some/file.html',      resolve: {config: 'Configuration' }, controller: 'AssessmentTheme as assessmentTheme'});
```

Then the test:

```
describe('testAuthor', function() {
    var controller, element, $modalInstance, config;


    beforeEach(module('testAuthor'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $httpBackend){
      $httpBackend.when('GET', 'some/url').respond([{},{},{}])
         controller = $controller("AssessmentTheme", {config: config})
    }))
    ....
    beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend){
        $httpBackend.flush();
    }))

    it('shoud do something', function(){
       expect(controller.config).toEqual([{},{},{}]);
    })
})
```

Here is what the controller does with the config:

```
.controller('AssessmentTheme', function (config) {
    this.config = {}
    angular.extend(this.config, config);
....
```

I have tried to put all sorts of different things into the response, but karma keeps failing, with the following message:

```
Expected Object({  }) to equal [ Object({  }), Object({  }), Object({  }) ]
```

I just can't figure out how to make the test to actually use the response coming from $httpBackend()

Is there anyone who see my problem and can lead me towards a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you declaring the config variable ?

Comment: I guess config should be set to the return value of the $http call

Comment: @NexusDuck: I've edited the code. Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly the response of the http call will be stored in a config variable in your controller ? Is this variable declared on the $scope?

Comment: @NexusDuck: I just edited some more. I think that should be all that is needed. Sorry for providing too little information. I'm pretty new to all of this :)

Comment: What are you testing here? It certainly doesn't look like the service. If you're testing the controller, you should really just mock the `Configuration` service.

Comment: Also, what does your controller do with `config`?

Comment: You realise `$http.get` returns a **promise**. I'd probably go with `config.then(function(thing) { that.config = thing; });` in your controller

Comment: @Phil I've added some more code, showing what the controller does with config.

Comment: @larschla yes, I saw that. Same thing applies. I don't know why you expect the `config` promise (object) to be the result of the promise resolution (array)